# Scroll to top in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

Hi all I have following [code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-iachev?file=index.js).

I am trying to scroll top, after every step.

I tried  this

```
    useEffect(() => {
      window.scrollTo(0, 0)
     }, [])
```

and even this

```
    window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: "smooth" });
```

But it didn't help in my case.

here is my code:
index.js file

```
    const App = () => {
      return (
        <div className="layout">
          <div className="imageContainer">
            <img src="http://imageipsum.com/800x600" />
          </div>
          <div className="steps">
            <Layout />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    };
```

Layout.js file

```
    const Layout = () => {
     const [current, setCurrent] = React.useState(0);

     const steps = [
     {
      title: 'First',
      content: <First setCurrent={setCurrent} />,
     },
     {
      title: 'Second',
      content: <Second setCurrent={setCurrent} />,
     },
     {
      title: 'Last',
      content: <Third setCurrent={setCurrent} />,
     },
     ];

    return (
      <>
        {steps[current].content}
        <div className="steps-action"></div>
      </>
     );
    };
```

First.js file (Second.js and Third.js file are same)

```
    const First = ({ setCurrent }) => {
      return (
        <>
          <div className="steps-content">
          <div>First</div>
          <div>First</div>
           ...
          <div>First</div>
         </div>
         <button
           onClick={() => {
              setCurrent(1);
             window.scrollTo({ top: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
           }}
          >
            Next
          </button>
        </>
      );
    };
```

and also css file

```
    .steps-content {
      text-align: center;
      background-color: #fafafa;
     }
    .layout {
      display: flex;
      grid-template-columns: 40% 60%;
     }
    .layout img {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100vh;
      object-fit: contain;
     }
    .imageContainer {
       background-color: aqua;
     }
    .steps {
      padding: 5.8rem 6.4rem;
      height: 100vh;
      overflow-y: auto;
      overflow-x: hidden;
     }

      .steps::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
         border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.158);
         padding: 2px 0;
         background-color: #40404031;
     }

    .steps::-webkit-scrollbar {
      width: 0.5rem;
      }

    .steps::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
      border-radius: 0.5rem;
      background-color: #737272a6;
      }
```

Be noticed when I am removing the  `overflow-y: auto;` and `overflow-x: hidden;` the scroll top functionality starting to work. But I need that  `overflow-y: auto;` and `overflow-x: hidden;`  line because I am changing the styles of that scroll bar.
Please help me to fix that problem, thаnks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the [solution](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-6ee3zb?file=Layout.js)

This [post](https://www.codegrepper.com/code-examples/javascript/how+to+scroll+to+top+of+div+in+react) helps me.

I add the following to my code.

```
     const myRef = useRef(null);
       myRef?.current?.scrollIntoView({ block: 'end', behavior: 'smooth' });

    return (
       <>
         <div ref={myRef}></div>
         {steps[current].content}
      </>
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

> **Modify your useEffect function**

```
useEffect(() => {

 setTimeout(() => {
 window.scrollTo(0, 0)
 }, 2000); 

 }, [])
```

You can increase the settimeout() function time according to your browser behaviour..

or the time it takes.... try different **milliseconds values**

Comment: Thank you for your response , but it not helped me...https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-2wht2s?file=components%2FFirst.js ... here is with useEffect